# Isolate N values from a list after obtaining a specific match with a regex

Tags: python, regex, loops

Looping through a big list of exactly 173754 strings (read in previously from a text file), I have an if statement looking for a match with a regular expression. Like so:

```
def filtering(a_list):
    for i in a_list:
            if re.search(r'\d{0,1}\s+Contacts;\s*', i) is not None:
```

What I'm trying to do is automatically append the next 5 elements to a second list after a match occurred. Writing a regular expression individually for these five elements is not possible because they have no special format or value. All I can do is grasp this one element preceding the information I actually want.

How can I get hold of the successive five elements?

I tried appending  the indexes of the matches and then get next five elements with a slice, problem is there are many duplicates in the list, so it obviously always returns the first lowest index.

The function gets called right after I read in the text file and format it slightly:

```
#Read in input file and somewhat format the text.
test_cases = open('input.txt', 'r')
for i in test_cases:
    if len(i) < 64 or i != ';':
        k = ';'.join(' '.join(line.split()) for line in i.split('\n'))
        #print(k)
        my_list.append(k)
#call first cleaning function with the formatted list as input. then close file
filtering(my_list)
test_cases.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
def filtering(a_list):
    results = []
    for i, item in enumerate(a_list):
        if re.search(r'\d{0,1}\s+Contacts;\s*', item) is not None:
            results.extend(a_list[i+1:i+6])
```